# Do the paired electrons of subshells' degenerate orbitals contribute to the total exchange energy?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, orbitals, transition-metals, periodic-trends

For instance, in d<sup>7</sup>, there are 5 electrons with the same spin, and 2 electron with the opposite spin, meaning that there are only 3 unpaired electrons. So, which of these would be correct?

[image]

(i) Total number of exchanges taking place = 3? (only unpaired electrons) 
or
(ii) Sum of individual exchanges of the same spin electrons, so 10 + 2 = 12?
Or is it something else entirely?

Also, if the first one is correct, then how do we explain the stability of d<sup>10</sup> over d<sup>5</sup>?

ALTERNATIVELY:
Does the pairing of electron reduce the exchange energy?